# stream_socket_accept() and fgetc stalls "randomly" in an otherwise working websocket server

Tags: php, sockets, websocket

I am running a webssocket server in php that does its job pretty well. Except one thing:

Sometimes stream_socket_accept() will stall for 60 seconds. This can happen seconds after the server has been started, it can also happen hours after the server has been started. I can not reproduce the behavior myself.

Sometimes it stalls at the call stream_socket_accept(), sometimes it stalls when reading the header from the client directly after stream_socket_accept has returned.

What's more: default_socket_timeout is set system wide to 10 seconds, and php.ini shows this value.

Even with stream_socket_accept($socket, 0); it will stall. The timeout given is simply ignored.

My questions:

1. Why does it stall in the first place? When the listener indicates a new connection, stream_socket_accept should not stall, should it?
2. Why the the fgetc stall on the very first byte of a connection (when retrieving the header of an incoming connection, right after stream_socket_accept()?
3. Why does it stall exactly 60 seconds (the standard default_timeout for sockets) when I definitely changed this to 10 seconds (showing in phpinfo()).

I am running out of ideas.

ANY idea is highly appreciated.

Here is the full code of the socket (which also does some agent managing logic wich works).

My hope is that somebody spots something.

```
<?php

// STALLING HAPPENS SOMETIMES IN LINE 52 fgetc()
// AND IN LINE 271 stream_socket_accept()

class WS {

    const
        //! UUID magic string
        Magic='258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11',
        //! Packet size
        Packet=65536;

    //@{ Mask bits for first byte of header
    const
        Text=0x01,
        Binary=0x02,
        Close=0x08,
        Ping=0x09,
        Pong=0x0a,
        OpCode=0x0f,
        Finale=0x80;
    //@}

    //@{ Mask bits for second byte of header
    const
        Length=0x7f;
    //@}

}

//! RFC6455 server socket
class Server {

    protected
        $addr,
        $ctx,
        $wait,
        $sockets,
        $agents=[],
        $events=[];

    /**
    *   Allocate stream socket
    *   @return NULL
    *   @param $socket resource
    **/
    function alloc($socket) {
        trace("Fetching http header...");        
        // if header does not start with "GET"
        // immediately close connection
        foreach( ['G','E','T'] as $get) {
            $character=fgetc($socket);
            $metadata=stream_get_meta_data($socket);

            // this MUST NOT BE REWRITTEN!
            // unread_bytes can not be checked against 0
            if ($character==$get && !feof($socket) && $metadata['unread_bytes'] > 0)
                continue;
            else {
                trace("Error: Header does not start with GET – connection closed");
                stream_socket_shutdown($socket,STREAM_SHUT_RDWR);
                return;
            }
        }

        $str="GET";
        do {
            $str.=fgetc($socket);
            $metadata=stream_get_meta_data($socket);
        } while (!feof($socket) && $metadata['unread_bytes'] > 0);

        // Get WebSocket headers
        $hdrs=[];
        $CRLF="\r\n";
        $verb=NULL;
        $uri=NULL;
        foreach (explode($CRLF,$str) as $line)
            if (preg_match('/^(\w+)\s(.+)\sHTTP\/1\.\d$/',
                trim($line),$match)) {
                $verb=$match[1];
                $uri=$match[2];
            }
            else
            if (preg_match('/^(.+): (.+)/',trim($line),$match))
                // Standardize header
                $hdrs[
                    strtr(
                        ucwords(
                            strtolower(
                                strtr($match[1],'-',' ')
                            )
                        ),' ','-'
                    )
                ]=$match[2];
        if (empty($hdrs['Upgrade']) &&
            empty($hdrs['Sec-Websocket-Key'])) {
            // Not a WebSocket request
            $this->write(
                $socket,
                $str='HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request'.$CRLF.
                    'Connection: close'.$CRLF.$CRLF
            );
            stream_socket_shutdown($socket,STREAM_SHUT_RDWR);
            // 1 @fclose($socket);
            return;
        }
        // Handshake
        $bytes=$this->write(
            $socket,
            $str='HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols'.$CRLF.
                'Upgrade: websocket'.$CRLF.
                'Connection: Upgrade'.$CRLF.
                'Sec-WebSocket-Accept: '.
                    base64_encode(
                        sha1(
                            $hdrs['Sec-Websocket-Key'].
                            WS::Magic,
                            TRUE
                        )
                    ).$CRLF.$CRLF
        );
        if (is_int($bytes)) {
            // Connect agent to server
            $this->sockets[]=$socket;
            $this->agents[(int)$socket]=
                new Agent($this,$socket,$verb,$uri,$hdrs);
        }
        else
            stream_socket_shutdown($socket,STREAM_SHUT_RDWR);
    }

    /**
    *   Free stream socket
    *   @return bool
    *   @param $socket resource
    **/
    function free($socket) {
        unset($this->sockets[array_search($socket,$this->sockets)]);
        unset($this->agents[(int)$socket]);
        stream_socket_shutdown($socket,STREAM_SHUT_WR);
        // 1 @fclose($socket);
    }

    /**
    *   Read from stream socket
    *   @return string|FALSE
    *   @param $socket resource
    **/
    function read($socket) {
        return is_string($str=@fread($socket,WS::Packet)) && strlen($str)?
            $str:
            FALSE;
    }

    /**
    *   Write to stream socket
    *   @return int|FALSE
    *   @param $socket resource
    *   @param $str string
    **/
    function write($socket,$str) {
        for ($i=0,$bytes=0;$i<strlen($str);$i+=$bytes) {
            if (($bytes=@fwrite($socket,substr($str,$i))) &&
                @fflush($socket))
                continue;
            return FALSE;
        }
        return $bytes;
    }

    /**
    *   Return socket agents
    *   @return array
    *   @param $uri string
    ***/
    function agents($uri=NULL) {
        return array_filter(
            $this->agents,
            function($val) use($uri) {
                return $uri?($val->uri()==$uri):TRUE;
            }
        );
    }

    /**
    *   Return event handlers
    *   @return array
    **/
    function events() {
        return $this->events;
    }

    /**
    *   Bind function to event handler
    *   @return object
    *   @param $event string
    *   @param $func callable
    **/
    function on($event,$func) {
        $this->events[$event]=$func;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
    *   Execute the server process
    *   @return object
    **/
    function run() {
        $fw=\Base::instance();
        // Activate WebSocket listener
        $listen=stream_socket_server(
            $this->addr,$errno,$errstr,
            STREAM_SERVER_BIND|STREAM_SERVER_LISTEN,
            $this->ctx
        );
        // stream_set_timeout($listen,0);
        stream_set_read_buffer($listen,WS::Packet);
        stream_set_write_buffer($listen,WS::Packet);
        $socket=socket_import_stream($listen);
        socket_set_option(
            $socket,
            SOL_SOCKET,
            SO_REUSEADDR,
            1
        );
        socket_set_option(
            $socket,
            SOL_SOCKET,
            SO_LINGER,
            ['l_onoff'=>1,'l_linger'=>1]
        );
        register_shutdown_function(function() use($listen) {
            foreach ($this->sockets as $socket)
                if ($socket!=$listen)
                    $this->free($socket);
            stream_socket_shutdown($listen,STREAM_SHUT_RDWR);
            @fclose($listen);
            if (isset($this->events['stop']) &&
                is_callable($func=$this->events['stop']))
                $func($this);
        });
        if ($errstr)
            user_error($errstr,E_USER_ERROR);
        if (isset($this->events['start']) &&
            is_callable($func=$this->events['start']))
            $func($this);
        $this->sockets=[$listen];
        $empty=[];
        $wait=$this->wait;
        while (TRUE) {
            $active=$this->sockets;
            $mark=microtime(TRUE);
            trace("Waiting for socket action...");
            $count=@stream_select(
                $active,$empty,$empty,(int)$wait,round(1e6*($wait-(int)$wait))
            );
            if (is_bool($count) && $wait) {
                if (isset($this->events['error']) &&
                    is_callable($func=$this->events['error']))
                    $func($this);
                die;
            }
            if ($count) {
                // Process active connections
                foreach ($active as $socket) {
                    if (!is_resource($socket))
                        continue;                       
                    if ($socket==$listen) {
                        trace("New connection pending...");
                        if ($socket=stream_socket_accept($listen)) {
                            $this->alloc($socket);
                            trace("alloc() finished");
                        }
                        else {
                            trace("Connection failed...");                      
                            continue;                           
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        $id=(int)$socket;
                        if (isset($this->agents[$id]) &&
                            $raw=$this->agents[$id]->fetch()) {
                            list($op,$data)=$raw;
                            // Dispatch
                            switch ($op & WS::OpCode) {
                            case WS::Text:
                                $data=trim($data);
                            case WS::Binary:
                            case WS::Pong:
                                if (isset($this->events['receive']) &&
                                    is_callable($func=$this->events['receive']))
                                    $func($this->agents[$id],$op,$data);
                                break;
                            case WS::Ping:
                                $this->agents[$id]->send(WS::Pong);
                                break;
                            default:
                                if (isset($this->events['invalid']) &&
                                    is_callable($func=$this->events['invalid']))
                                    $func($this->agents[$id],$op,$data);
                            case WS::Close:
                                $this->free($socket);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                $wait-=microtime(TRUE)-$mark;
                while ($wait<1e-6) {
                    $wait+=$this->wait;
                    $count=0;
                }
            }
            if (!$count) {
                $mark=microtime(TRUE);
                foreach ($this->sockets as $socket) {
                    if (!is_resource($socket))
                        continue;
                    $id=(int)$socket;
                    if ($socket!=$listen &&
                        isset($this->agents[$id]) &&
                        is_string($this->agents[$id]->send(WS::Ping)) &&
                        isset($this->events['idle']) &&
                        is_callable($func=$this->events['idle']))
                        $func($this->agents[$id]);
                }
                $wait=$this->wait-microtime(TRUE)+$mark;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
    *   Instantiate object
    *   @return object
    *   @param $addr string
    *   @param $ctx resource
    *   @param $wait int
    **/
    function __construct($addr,$ctx=NULL,$wait=60) {
        $this->addr=$addr;
        $this->ctx=$ctx?:stream_context_create();
        $this->wait=$wait;
        $this->events=[];
    }

}

//! RFC6455 remote socket
class Agent {

    protected
        $server,
        $id,
        $socket,
        $flag,
        $verb,
        $uri,
        $headers,
        $events,
        $buffer='';

    /**
    *   Return server instance
    *   @return object
    **/
    function server() {
        return $this->server;
    }

    /**
    *   Return socket ID
    *   @return string
    **/
    function id() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
    *   Return request method
    *   @return string
    **/
    function verb() {
        return $this->verb;
    }

    /**
    *   Return request URI
    *   @return string
    **/
    function uri() {
        return $this->uri;
    }

    /**
    *   Return socket headers
    *   @return string
    **/
    function headers() {
        return $this->headers;
    }

    /**
    *   Frame and transmit payload
    *   @return string|FALSE
    *   @param $socket resource
    *   @param $op int
    *   @param $payload string
    **/
    function send($op,$data='') {
        $mask=WS::Finale | $op & WS::OpCode;
        $len=strlen($data);
        $str='';
        if ($len<126)
            $str=pack('CC',$mask,$len);
        else
        if ($len>125 && $len<65536)
            $str=pack('CCn',$mask,126,$len);
        else
        if ($len>65535)
            $str=pack('CCNN',$mask,127,$len);
        $str.=$data;
        $server=$this->server();
        if (is_bool($server->write($this->socket,$str))) {
            $server->free($this->socket);
            return FALSE;
        }
        if (!in_array($op,[WS::Pong,WS::Close]) &&
            isset($this->events['send']) &&
            is_callable($func=$this->events['send']))
            $func($this,$op,$data);
        return $data;
    }

    /**
    *   Retrieve and unmask payload
    *   @return array|FALSE
    **/
    function fetch() {
        // Unmask payload
        $server=$this->server();
        if (is_bool($str=$server->read($this->socket))) {
            $server->free($this->socket);
            return FALSE;
        }
        $buf=($this->buffer.=$str);
        $op=ord($buf[0]) & WS::OpCode;
        $len=ord($buf[1]) & WS::Length;
        $pos=2;
        if ($len==126) {
            $len=ord($buf[2])*256+ord($buf[3]);
            $pos+=2;
        }
        else
        if ($len==127) {
            for ($i=0,$len=0;$i<8;$i++)
                $len=$len*256+ord($buf[$i+2]);
            $pos+=8;
        }
        for ($i=0,$mask=[];$i<4;$i++)
            $mask[$i]=ord($buf[$pos+$i]);
        $pos+=4;
        if (strlen($buf)<$len+$pos)
            return FALSE;
        $this->buffer='';
        for ($i=0,$data='';$i<$len;$i++)
            $data.=chr(ord($buf[$pos+$i])^$mask[$i%4]);
        return [$op,$data];
    }

    /**
    *   Destroy object
    *   @return NULL
    **/
    function __destruct() {
        if (isset($this->events['disconnect']) &&
            is_callable($func=$this->events['disconnect']))
            $func($this);
    }

    /**
    *   Instantiate object
    *   @return object
    *   @param $server object
    *   @param $socket resource
    *   @param $verb string
    *   @param $uri string
    *   @param $hdrs array
    **/
    function __construct($server,$socket,$verb,$uri,array $hdrs) {
        $this->server=$server;
        $this->id=stream_socket_get_name($socket,TRUE);
        $this->socket=$socket;
        $this->verb=$verb;
        $this->uri=$uri;
        $this->headers=$hdrs;
        $this->events=$server->events();
        if (isset($this->events['connect']) &&
            is_callable($func=$this->events['connect']))
            $func($this);
    }

}

/**
*   Simple console logger
*   @return NULL
*   @param $line string
**/
function trace($line) {
    echo "\r".date('H:i:s').' '.$line.PHP_EOL;
}

/**
*   Process handler for graceful exit (routed to registered shutdown handler)
*   @return NULL
**/
function kill($signal) {
    die;
}

pcntl_signal(SIGINT,'kill');
pcntl_signal(SIGTERM,'kill');

if (PHP_SAPI!='cli') {
    // Prohibit direct HTTP access
    header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
    die;
}

chdir(__DIR__);

require('lib/base.php');
error_reporting((E_ALL|E_STRICT)&~(E_NOTICE|E_USER_NOTICE|E_WARNING|E_USER_WARNING));

// Load .ini files
$fw=Base::instance();

$fw->
    config('app/ini/config.ini')->
    config('app/ini/dev.ini');

if (!is_file($pid='ws.pid') ||
    !is_dir('/proc/'.file_get_contents($pid))) {

    // Override any error handler specified in .ini files
    ini_set('error_log','/dev/null');
    $fw->DEBUG=2;
    $fw->ONERROR=function($fw) {
        trace($fw->get('ERROR.text'));
        foreach (explode("\n",trim($fw->get('ERROR.trace'))) as $line)
            trace($line);
    };

    $fw->VERBOSE=(bool)preg_grep('/[\/-]v/',$argv);

    // Instantiate the server
    $ws=new Server(
        $fw->get('SITE.websocket'),
        stream_context_create([
            'ssl'=>$fw->get('SSL')+[
                'allow_self_signed'=>TRUE,
                'verify_peer'=>FALSE
            ]
        ])
    );

    // Intercept OpenSSL errors
    $err=FALSE;
    while (TRUE)
        if ($msg=openssl_error_string()) {
            $err=TRUE;
            trace($msg);
        }
        else
            break;
    if ($err)
        die;

    $ws->
        on('start',function($server) use($fw) {
            trace('WebSocket server started ('.$fw->get('SITE.websocket').')');
            file_put_contents('ws.pid',getmypid());
        })->
        on('error',function($server) use($fw) {
            if ($err=socket_last_error()) {
                trace(socket_strerror($err));
                socket_clear_error();
            }
            if ($err=error_get_last())
                trace($err['message']);
        })->
        on('stop',function($server) use($fw) {
            trace('Shutting down ('.$fw->get('SITE.websocket').')');
            @unlink('ws.pid');
        })->
        on('connect',function($agent) use($fw) {
            trace(
                '(0x00'.$agent->uri().') '.$agent->id().' connected '.
                '<'.(count($agent->server()->agents())+1).'>'
            );
            if ($fw->VERBOSE) {
                $hdrs=$agent->headers();
                trace(
                    $hdrs['User-Agent'].' '.
                    '[v'.$hdrs['Sec-Websocket-Version'].']'
                );
            }
            $agent->hash=dechex(crc32(file_get_contents(__FILE__)));
            $agent->feature=[];
            $agent->query='';
            $agent->session=[];
        })->
        on('disconnect',function($agent) use($fw) {
            trace('(0x08'.$agent->uri().') '.$agent->id().' disconnected');
            if ($err=socket_last_error()) {
                trace(socket_strerror($err));
                socket_clear_error();
            }
            if (preg_match('/^\/(.+)/',$agent->uri(),$match)) {
                $class='WebSocket\\'.$match[1];
                if (isset($agent->feature[$class])) {
                    $obj=$agent->feature[$class];
                    foreach ($agent->feature as $key=>$obj)
                        if (is_callable([$obj,'disconnect']))
                            $fw->call([$obj,'disconnect'],[$fw,$agent]);
                }
            }
        })->
        on('idle',function($agent) use($fw) {
            foreach ($agent->feature as $key=>$obj)
                if (is_callable([$obj,'idle']))
                    $fw->call([$obj,'idle'],[$fw,$agent]);
        })->
        on('receive',function($agent,$op,$data) use($fw) {
            switch($op) {
            case WS::Pong:
                $text='pong';
                break;
            case WS::Text:
                $data=trim($data);
            case WS::Binary:
                $text='data';
                break;
            default:
                $text='unknown';
                break;
            }
            trace(
                '(0x'.str_pad(dechex($op),2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).
                $agent->uri().') '.$agent->id().' '.$text.' received'
            );
            if ($op==WS::Text && $data) {
                if ($fw->VERBOSE)
                    trace($data);
                $in=json_decode($data,TRUE);
                if (json_last_error()==JSON_ERROR_NONE &&
                    preg_match('/^\/(.+)/',$agent->uri(),$match)) {
                    $class='WebSocket\\'.$match[1];
                    if (isset($agent->feature[$class])) {
                        if (isset($in['query']))
                            $agent->query=$in['query'];
                        if (isset($in['session']))
                            foreach ($in['session'] as $key=>$val)
                                $agent->session[$key]=$val;
                        $obj=$agent->feature[$class];
                        if (isset($in['func']) &&
                            is_callable([$obj,$in['func']]))
                            $fw->call([$obj,$in['func']],[$fw,$agent]);
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    if (isset($in['nonce']) &&
                        isset($agent->headers()['Cookie']) &&
                        preg_match(
                            '/PHPSESSID=(\w+)/',
                            $agent->headers()['Cookie'],
                            $match
                        ) &&
                        Bcrypt::instance()->
                            verify($match[1],'$2y$12$'.$in['nonce'])) {
                        if (isset($in['session']))
                            foreach ($in['session'] as $key=>$val)
                                $agent->session[$key]=$val;
                        if (empty($agent->feature[$class]))
                            $agent->feature[$class]=new $class($fw,$agent);
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                        trace(
                            '(0x00'.$agent->uri().') '.$agent->id().' '.
                            'authentication failed');
                }
            }
        })->
        on('send',function($agent,$op,$data) use($fw) {
            switch($op) {
            case WS::Ping:
                $text='ping';
                break;
            case WS::Text:
                $data=trim($data);
            case WS::Binary:
                $text='data';
                break;
            default:
                $text='unknown';
                break;
            }
            trace(
                '(0x'.str_pad(dechex($op),2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).
                $agent->uri().') '.$agent->id().' '.$text.' sent'
            );
            if ($op==WS::Text && $fw->VERBOSE)
                trace($data);
        })->
        on('invalid',function($agent,$op,$data) use($fw) {
            trace(
                '(0x'.str_pad(dechex($op),2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).
                $agent->uri().') '.$agent->id().' invalid opcode'
            );
        })->
        run();

}
else
    trace('A socket server instance is already running!');
```

Answer (score -1):

This is partly an answer to the question:

The timeout was ignored because php-cli uses a different php.ini, of course. I completely forgot this. a simple ini_set did the trick.